# WebSocket сервер - websocketd. Как получить данные в php-обработчик? Пример

Tags: websocket, https

Библиотека **websocketd** уже установлена и работает. С приёмом - передачей на **js** проблем у меня не возникло, а вот с приёмом данных на **php-обработчик** загвоздка. Поделитесь пожалуйста конструкцией. Передать нужно всего 3 переменные.

**1. Вопрос первый**: как правильно запустить **php-обработчик** с **websocketd** одной командой? Запуск **websocketd** и **php-обработчика** таким образом (*пример ниже*) не приносит результата, хотя тестовый вариант **bash-обработчика** (*count.sh*) с сайта http://websocketd.com работает:

- **$ websocketd --port=8008 ./count.sh** - прекрасно работает
- **$ websocketd --port=8008 php /<путь до обработчика>/handler.php** - не работает

**Код обработчика пока самый простой - ответить в сокет:**

```
<?php echo 'Answer from the handler'; ?>
```

**"Дёргаю" WebSocket c другого домена соответственно таким js-скриптом:**

```
<script src="reconnecting-websocket.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var ws    = new ReconnectingWebSocket('ws://<ip-адрес сервера>:8008/');
  var msg = {
      first_variable:  'aaaaaaaa', 
      second_variable: 'bbbbbbbb', 
      third_variable:  1
  };
  //ws.debug = true;
  ws.reconnectInterval = 10000;

  ws.onopen = function() {
      console.log('Data sent');
  };

  ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

  ws.onclose = function() {
      console.log('Connection closed: ' + event.data);
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log('Answer: ' + event.data);
  };
</script>
```

Но в ответ в консоли браузера это (видно что отправляет, но не принимает):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2. Вопрос второй**: какой будет код **php-обработчика**, чтобы принять данные?